# time.Parse offset parsing fails with "cannot parse <x>00 as -0700"

Tags: go

I wish to convert a string timestamp (for which no timezone was provided) to a `time` with timezone of UTC -08:00.

Code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    layout := "1/02/2006 15:04:05 -700"
    cellContent := "7/28/2021 22:45:34"
    t, err := time.Parse(layout, fmt.Sprintf("%s %s", cellContent, "-800"))
    if err == nil {
        fmt.Println(t.String())
    } else {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

This fails with message:

> parsing time "7/28/2021 22:45:34 -800" as "1/02/2006 15:04:05 -700":
> cannot parse "800" as " -700"

I believe I have an error in my layout string, but haven't been able to identify it.  What am I doing wrong?

[Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/Wrt7Ma_DXK5)

Comment: It looks like that format is not supported. If you change the format to `-0700` and the string to `-0800`, it works: https://go.dev/play/p/Pk_kHe2TNsB

Comment: @Adrian nailed it here: layout timezone must have a leading zero.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

See comment from @Adrian, who nailed it.
The layout timezone must have a leading zero.  Thanks!